# Define a dynamic variable name and use it before its definition

Tags: counters, variable, csname

I searched on the Internet but I did not find any solution for my problem, so I ask here.

**Short Question**

Is there a way to define a dynamic variable name in LaTex and use it before its definition?

**Context**

I have a large tex file; in one part I have sections included from external files. I don’t want to change the content of the external files before the include as they are generated from an external source. I can still change the template of the external file, so in the files I add dynamically created label and variable based on the value of a counter.

The objective is to dynamically create a summary of this part of the document **before it**. I can easily reference to the dynamic label either before or after the definition. But I can only access the value of the variable after the definition.

`main.tex`

```latex
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \nameref{foo:1}: \csname fooscore1\endcsname
    \item \nameref{foo:2}: \csname fooscore2\endcsname
\end{itemize}

\newcounter{foo}

\input{section1}

\input{section2}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \nameref{foo:1}: \csname fooscore1\endcsname
    \item \nameref{foo:2}: \csname fooscore2\endcsname
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

`section1.tex`

```latex
\section{section1}

\stepcounter{foo}
\label{foo:\thefoo}
\expandafter\def\csname fooscore\thefoo \endcsname{10}

Counter: \thefoo\\
Score: \csname fooscore\thefoo\endcsname
```

`section2.tex`

```latex
\section{section2}

\stepcounter{foo}
\label{foo:\thefoo}
\expandafter\def\csname fooscore\thefoo \endcsname{20}

Counter: \thefoo\\
Score: \csname fooscore\thefoo\endcsname
```

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way to access the value of the `fooscore1` and `fooscore2` before the include (like the dynamic label)? Note that the value of the fooscores are not necessarily integers.

I try to cheat by creating a dummy section with the value of the variable as title and the variable name as label, but I cannot find a way to hide it from both the document and the table of content.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: using a generated label like `\label{foo:\thefoo}` negates almost all the use of `\label` why can you not use fixed strings?

Comment: but if you want the text to be available then you need to treat it like the referenced value, write the definition to the aux file so that it is available for the whole document on the next run.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Thank you for your answer! As explained, the files are generated separetly so each one have no idea what is the curent counter value. How can I add it as a refereced to the aux file at the compilation time?

Comment: The aux file contains TeX code and the old one is read/expanded at \begin{document}.  If you look at it you will find things like \newlabel which stores the information used by \ref.  Since this information is not always available, you should have a plan B with \@ifundefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use another label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \nameref{foo:1}: \ref*{score:1}
    \item \nameref{foo:2}: \ref*{score:2}
\end{itemize}

\newcounter{foo}

\section{section1}
\stepcounter{foo}
\label{foo:\thefoo}
\expandafter\def\csname fooscore\thefoo \endcsname{10}
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabel{\csname fooscore\thefoo \endcsname}
\makeatletter
\label{score:\thefoo}

Counter: \thefoo\\
Score: \csname fooscore\thefoo\endcsname

\section{section2}
\stepcounter{foo}
\label{foo:\thefoo}
\expandafter\def\csname fooscore\thefoo \endcsname{20}
\makeatletter
\def\@currentlabel{\csname fooscore\thefoo \endcsname}
\makeatletter
\label{score:\thefoo}

Counter: \thefoo\\
Score: \csname fooscore\thefoo\endcsname

\end{document}
```

You can also look at zref which offers extended possibilities to store values and reference them.

[image]

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much for the help.